# deploy 2 flask projects using apache on Ubuntu (not duplicated)

Tags: apache, flask

please don't close the question as duplicated as it is a different issue.

I have an ubuntu server on Azure and I deployed a flask project on it and it is working fine, I wanted to deploy another project but it doesn't work, here is my sites.conf, please review it and tell me where is the issue.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName server
       ServerAdmin admin@email.com
       ServerAlias project1.net
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1/
       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/project1/project1.wsgi
       WSGIPassAuthorization on
       <Directory /var/www/html/project1/>
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Directory>
       Alias /static /var/www/html/project1/static
       <Directory /var/www/html/project1/static/>
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Directory>

       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       LogLevel warn
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName server
       ServerAdmin admin@email.com
       ServerAlias project2.net
       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project2/
       WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/project2/project2.wsgi
       WSGIPassAuthorization on
       <Directory /var/www/html/project2/>
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Directory>
       Alias /static /var/www/html/project2/static
       <Directory /var/www/html/project2/static/>
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from all
       </Directory>
       ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
       LogLevel warn
       CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```